# Jest ES6 Modules: Cannot use import statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm writing an ES6 application. I have the `"type": "module"` in `package.json`.

`devDependencies` are:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.11.28",
    "coveralls": "^3.1.1",
    "husky": "^9.0.11",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "miragejs": "^0.1.48",
    "npm-check-updates": "^16.14.15",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tsx": "^4.7.1",
    "typescript": "^5.4.2"
  }
```

And `jest.config.ts` as follows:

```ts
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^public-ip$": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/publicIp.js", // Mocking the public-ip module
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/dist/",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/",
  ],
  preset: "ts-jest",
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"
  ],
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
};
```

It works, but when I add a `miragejs` configuration in `jest.setup.js`:

```js
import { makeServer } from "./src/__tests__/__mocks__/server";

let server = null;

beforeEach(() => {
  server = makeServer({environment: "test"});
  /**
   * Enable logging of the server
   */
  // server.logging = true;
});

afterEach(() => server.shutdown());
```

I get the infamous error:

```
    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /home/sineverba/sviluppo/personali/docker-cloudflare-ddns/jest.setup.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { makeServer } from "./src/__tests__/__mocks__/server";
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What I tried:

1. imported babel: `npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/preset-env @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`
2. Added `babel.config.js` into root project

   ```json
   {
     "presets": [
       "@babel/preset-env",
       "@babel/preset-typescript"
     ],
     "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
   }
   ```
3. Added `node-experimental` node --experimental-modules` in package.json before launching Jest.

How can I get rid of the error?

- Application itself works. It runs. I have problem only with Jest. So, ts-node is already configured.
- I use `package.json`, and this is the scripts section:

  ```json
   "scripts": {
      "start": "npx tsx src/index.ts",
      "build": "tsc",
      "test": "jest --watch",
      "coverage": "jest --coverage",
      "lint": "tslint -p tsconfig.json",
      "prettier": "prettier -c \"src/**/*.ts\"",
      "fixprettier": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\"",
      "prepare": "husky"
    },
  ```

I edit `jest.config.ts` as follows:

```
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: [".ts"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^public-ip$": "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/publicIp.js", // Mocking the public-ip module
  },
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "<rootDir>/dist/",
    "<rootDir>/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/",
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  testEnvironment: "node",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": [
      "ts-jest",
      ,
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

If I remove references to the `miragejs` server, Jest works (of course, it doesn't find the import instruction any more).

Comment: You don't appear to have even tried to configure `ts-node` for ESM, read their docs to see how: https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/imports

Comment: @jonrsharpe Updated question. Application itselfs works and runs, issue is only with jest.

Comment: @guest271314 How your comment can help me?

Comment: There's no point adding Babel config because you're _not using Babel_. You're using ts-jest: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/

Comment: @guest271314 that flag was for node 12 and 14. There hasn't been anything experimental about ESM support since v16, you simply use files with (originally necessary but today ridiculous) .mjs extension, or you use type:module in package.json and the latter is _by far_ the better solution.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and in effect I removed that flag. Now use "type: module" in package but it doesn't work with jest.

Comment: @jonrsharpe saw your link for ts-jest configuration, but cannot have luck. See new update #2.

Comment: I probably gave the wrong impression in my reply to the user with all the numbers in their name: _you_ still need that flag [as per the Jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) because Jest's ESM support in Jest is still not done, thanks to Node dragging its feet on severeal issues, see https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/9430). So I'd recommend starting in an empty dir for a moment. Set up the basics with a two files, one importing the other, and then set up jest to run a single test. Get that working, then port what you learned to your real codebase.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans No, those are newer flags. version 20 and version 21 https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v21-release-announce. I don't ordinarily use an `.mjs` extension or a `package.json` file. I use `.js` extension with no `package.json` file and `node` (nightly) executable standalone, so I can run the same code in `deno` or `bun`.

Comment: I know this sounds too simple, but have you tried renaming to `jest.setup.ts`?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with importing MirageJS seems to be linked to how its modules are understood in the Jest setup. Since MirageJS is an add-on for Ember CLI, its module system might not be fully ready to work seamlessly with a Jest environment set up for ES modules.

Try to simplify your jest setup for typescript something like this:

```
import type { Config } from '@jest/types';

// Jest configuration for TypeScript with ES Modules
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // Use the ESM preset for ts-jest
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      useESM: true,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1', // Redirect .js imports to their .ts counterparts
    '^public-ip$': '<rootDir>/src/__tests__/__mocks__/publicIp.js',
  },
  transform: {}, // Override to prevent jest from transforming
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'], // Treat .ts files as ES Modules
  testEnvironment: 'node', // Specify the environment in which the tests are run
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'], // Setup file for Jest
};

export default config;
```